# import demo project issue using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded this file [ActivityLifecycle.zip](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and now i am trying to import it using Package Explorer. So, I selected Import->Existing project into workspace, clicked Next, next selected root directory, but nothing happened. The projects field is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract 'activity-lifecycle' folder from that ZIP file to Desktop.
2. Right-Click on Explorer and click on Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace.
3. Select 'activity-lifecycle' folder at Desktop.
4. Click Finish button.

**(If that doesn't work then)**

1. Extract 'activity-lifecycle' folder from that ZIP file to Desktop.
2. Press CTRL+N select Android -> Android Project from Existing Code.
3. Select 'activity-lifecycle' folder at Desktop.
4. Click Finish button.

Comment: @Matrosov Alexander It is strange that File|New Android Project| Existing Code fails.